# What does "data is stored in deserialized format" in Spark mean?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark caching storage levels, the MEMORY_ONLY storage level stores data in memory in "deserialized format". Aren't data usually held as binary in memory? So what does deserialized format mean here? What does it mean for a dataframe in python?

Comment: Can u accept answer?

Answer (score 0):

From https://medium.com/illumination/managing-memory-and-disk-resources-in-pyspark-with-cache-and-persist-aa08026929e2 that gives good overview.

Deseralized is more space but saving on compute to deserialize, for actual usage that is. Choice of programmer.

1. MEMORY_ONLY: This level stores the RDD in memory as deserialized Java objects. This is the default level used by cache() and persist(). It provides fast access to the data, but if the RDD does not fit entirely in memory, it may need to be recomputed from the original data source.
2. MEMORY_ONLY_SER: This level stores the RDD or DataFrame in memory as serialized Java objects. This can reduce memory usage compared to MEMORY_ONLY, but accessing the data requires deserialization, which can be slower than using deserialized objects.
3. MEMORY_AND_DISK: This level stores the RDD or DataFrame in memory as deserialized Java objects, but if the RDD or DataFrame does not fit entirely in memory, it spills the excess data to disk. This provides better performance than recomputing the data, but accessing data from disk can be slower than accessing it from memory.
4. MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER: This level stores the RDD or DataFrame in memory as serialized Java objects, and spills excess data to disk if needed. This can be useful when memory usage is a concern, but accessing the data requires deserialization, which can be slower than using deserialized objects.
5. DISK_ONLY: This level stores the RDD or DataFrame on disk only, and not in memory. This can be useful when memory usage is a concern and the data does not fit entirely in memory, but accessing the data from disk can be slower than accessing it from memory.

Comment: FYI Unlike RDD, dataframe's default storage level is MEMORY_AND_DISK, see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/CacheManager.scala#L86)

Comment: in your answer there are two terms "serialized java objects" and "deserialized java objects"? what do they mean? isn't data stored as binary in memory already? so what is the difference between the above two? is this serialization and deserialization done by "Encoders"?

Comment: Non readable and readable. That simple.

Comment: https://hazelcast.com/glossary/serialization/

Comment: Let me know if I understood it right: object has three components: state, identity and behavior. After serializing, only the object's state is converted into binary, right? @thebluephantom

Comment: non-readable for the programming language?

Comment: Until deserialized

Comment: got it! and encoders are not involved in serializing for data transfer right?

Comment: Serializing is creating a bytestream regardless

Comment: Maybe an idea to accept answer as you got it. Serialization is used everywhere